# Setting Hystrix timeout with environment variable

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

In order to change Hystrix's default request timeout (1000ms), one must set the following property :
             `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=2000`

What is the corresponding environment variable ?

I would like to "tune" the timeout on my favorite cloud platform without touching the source code first.
I'm pretty sure this one doesn't work : `HYSTRIX_COMMAND_DEFAULT_EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS=2000`

---

EDIT : Problem was found with Spring Cloud Camden / Spring Boot 1.4.

Comment: Have you tried `HYSTRIX_COMMAND_DEFAULT_EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUTINMILLISECONDS`?

Comment: @spencergibb nope, does not work either. I even tried `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds` as an environment variable without success. I'll try with `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={ "hystrix" : { "command" : { ... } } }` (probably the worse property to use with JSON syntax)

Comment: Got it to work locally with `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` env variable... for some reason the app fails to start on Elastic Beanstalk with the same environment variable, but that's another story.

Comment: @MichaelTecourt The `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds` string from your comment actually contains two invisible unicode chars between 'In' and 'Milliseconds' - `\u200C` and `\u200B`, watch out!

Answer (score 9):

VM options and environment variables can be referenced from application configuration, which is often a more convenient way to set properties with longer names.

For example, one can define the following reference in `application.yml`:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: ${service.timeout}
```

which will be resolved from the VM option `-Dservice.timeout=10000`, setting the default Hystrix command timeout to 10 seconds. It is even simpler with environment variables - thanks to [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), any of these will work (`export` examples are for Linux):

- `export service.timeout=10000`
- `export service_timeout=10000`
- `export SERVICE.TIMEOUT=10000`
- `export SERVICE_TIMEOUT=10000`

The common approach is to use `lowercase.dot.separated` for VM arguments and `ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` for environment variables.

Comment: it requires to modify the sources, but it's a clever workaround as a custom variable can also be bound to `ribbon.ReadTimeout` (which often needs to be modified along with hystrix's timeout)

Comment: @MichaelTecourt Out of curiosity, I've tried both `-Dhystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutinMilliseconds=10000` JVM argument and `export HYSTRIX_COMMAND_DEFAULT_EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUTINMILLISECONDS=10000` environment property, and they both worked for Spring Boot 1.5.3 and Spring Cloud Dalston.RELEASE. Try debugging `com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration#getList` for `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutinMilliseconds` key to see what is actually returned.

Comment: NOT work for me neither. Debug and find that `EnvironmentConfiguration.map` is a Hashmap and its key is still `HYSTRIX_COMMAND_DEFAULT_EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUTINMILLISECONDS`. Spring Boot 1.5.22 and Spring Cloud Dalston.SR1.

Comment: @jihor Did you use any @ConfigurationProperties beans since the magic comes from the relaxed binding? `Spring Boot uses some relaxed rules for binding Environment properties to @ConfigurationProperties beans...` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Answer (score 2):

You could try expression with a default value:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutIn‌Milliseconds: ${SERVICE_TIMEOUT:2000}
```

In case you have `SERVICE_TIMEOUT`system variable - it will be used by an application, otherwise, a default value will be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Found more of a workaround than a solution, using [SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) environment variable :

`SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{ "hystrix" : { "command" : { "default" : { "execution" : { "isolation" : { "thread" : { "timeoutInMilliseconds" : 3000 } } } } } } }'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring config yaml file , Please read further on following link

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/321

Comment: My question was about finding how to use `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds` as an environment variable. I know it works fine in a config file, I just want to override the property without needing to repackage the application.

Comment: If repackaging is your concern, you can try an external configuration file (eg: on the disk) that overrides the packaged properties file. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Answer (score 0):

VM option `-Dhystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=2000` works for me. However it has a side effect, then you can not change the config value in java code since system properties are prioritized.

```
ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty(
"hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", 3000);// it doesn't work
```